# CKEditor and sticky footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, sticky-footer

I am facing a problem. I use a "sticky" footer on my website. It works ok, but not on pages where CKEditor (4.6.2) is used. Problem is: there is an extra 1px-line after the footer. I believe I understand why problem occurs, but I am not sure how to fix it. Could you, please, suggest a workaround?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <header></header>
            <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
            </script>
        </div>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.content-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
.content-wrapper:after {
    content: "";
}
header {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
header:after {
    content: "";
}
footer {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
footer:after {
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing it. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWOrbb  Please create a complete, verifiable demo reproducing the problem http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MichaelCoker, ok, now that's interesting! Damn, I tried to replace my local instance of CKEditor with CDN version as in your example and problem disappeared. It is really strange, because I didn't modify my local instance at all... just unzipped and that's it. Not sure why this happens...

Comment: damn interesting indeed! I assumed you left off some markup/css or something. I can post this as an answer if you think it's useful/helpful, just lemme know.

Comment: @MichaelCoker, one more thing! If you try to replace your CDN script to `<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/full/ckeditor.js"></script>` (full version instead of standard), you will see this bug! I think one of CKEditor plugins messes something up.